# unity android game not working perfectly on nougat version

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-7.0-nougat

I have a project that is completely working on android lollipop but when I build my project in Nougat version it seems not working properly.

the process of my game is when the puzzle is finished or completed a modal will appear the way I did it is I move the game object to the last sibling like this `gameObject.transform.SetAsLastSibling();`. Its working completely on android lollipop but not in Nougat. Any Ideas what went wrong?

ps. my unity version is `5.6.2f1`

Comment: any one can anwer this pls? I really need some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lollipop and Nougat operate slightly differently. Seeing as that line of code doesn't do anything platform specific, I'd be one to guess that answer lies elsewhere (Unless this is a bug).

1. Make sure your android JDK is up to date.
2. Make sure the correct platforms have been installed in your SDK manager.
3. Completely uninstall the app, clean, build and try again.
4. If your app is using permissions then in Nougat you must request these at run time.

Links:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-GettingStarted.html